# C++ Specialization with a templated class

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, specialization

I cannot manage to specialize a template class function with a templated class.

```
class Incrementer
{
  int calculate(int n)  {return n++; }
};

template <int N>
class Multiplier
{
  int calculate(int n) { return n * N; }
};

template <class C>
class Storer
{
  void Store(const C&, std::ostream&) const;
  void ToFile(const C& toStore, const std::string& fileName) const { Store(toStore, std::ofstream(fileName)); }
};

template <> void Storer<Incrementer>::Store(const Incrementer& incrementer, std::ostream& os) const
{
  os << "Incrementer";
}

template <int N> template<> void Storer<Multiplier<N>>::Store(const Multiplier<N>& multiplier, std::ostream& os) const
{
  os << "Multiplier." << N;
}
```

The specialization for Incrementer compiles but the one for the templated class Multiplier does not.

Here is the error message I got: **invalid use of incomplete type ‘class Storer<Multiplier< N > >’**

Does anyone know what I did wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can only specialize the template class itself, and not a single method in that class.

Comment: It worked for the class Incrementer though.

Comment: Full specialization is allowed, partial specialization isn't.

Comment: What if I remove the class Storer and Store is just a template function:
` template <class C> void Store(const C&, std::ostream&);`
How do I specialize Store with the templated class Multipliier?

Comment: Function templates can't be partially specialized, but you can overload the function instead.